# Problems optimizing redis

Tags: node.js, redis

I have some webscraped data. I'm using redis as my server and fetching data from nodejs and displaying it in react.

This is what I have:

2 redis keys both ~ 200kb (so far, this will become ~10-20 mb in the future)

I fetch data from redis by getting both keys, parsing the data and then sending it. Just to note I'm storing data as one big string in the keys.

express:

```
 try {
    // Fetch redis data
    const data1 = await GET_ASYNC('data1');
    const data2 = await GET_ASYNC('data2');

    // Parse data
    const parse1 = JSON.parse(data1);
    const parse2 = JSON.parse(data2);

    const result = [...data2, ...data1];

    res.send(filterResults);

  } catch (err) {
    
    //
  }
```

The problem is that nodejs takes about ~2000ms to fetch and send the data, for my situation I need to lower this to 500ms or less. How could I do this? Is my problem in nodejs or how I'm storing data in redis? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to go for smaller keys instead of just 2 large keys. This will have few advantages i.e.

1. you will save on the network time to transfer such huge data.
2. you will save on the processing too at the nodejs side by not having to parse a big json structure.
3. Also, it would be easier for you to maintain smaller data structures in case you need to delete any of the keys by just adding an expiry to it, where as in case of 1 big structure you will have to maintain deletion of the data manually

Comment: But wont the network load be the same when fetching thousands of small keys rather than one big string?

Comment: @user It wouldn't be the same. You can fetch small keys concurrently

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions:

1. compress the data before save and after get. The compress cost is worthy.
2. bigkey operation will block Redis, try split datas to different Redis instance.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I just have a question. If I split my data up into 5 keys, wont I have to have this line 5 times: `const data1 = await GET_ASYNC('data1')` and samething for the parsing. That's the main reason I grouped my data into a big structure

Comment: If you split you data into 5 keys, you should execute `get` command for 5 times. If the 5 keys store in the same redis instance, you will cost more than no spliting. If the 5 keys store in 5 different redis instance, the `get` command will speed up because of each key is smaller. Notice that, you should not use `await GET_ASYNC`， change the code to `GET_ASYNC` for 5 times with callback, then await all geted.